# How to install git-lfs on hp-ux

Tags: git, hp-ux

I was able to install git using swinstall & [depot file](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Development/Tools/git-2.18.0/),
and after installing all dependencies it works.

I cannot find any depot file for [git-lfs extension](https://git-lfs.github.com/):

Is there any easy way to install git-lfs on HP-UX?

Comment: Build it from source?

Comment: hmmm I thought about it... but here https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Installation
it says it requires GO compiler... and I couldn't find any for HP-UX

Comment: Hm, good point. I don't see one either. But since you should have retired that thing a few eons ago, it's probably just as well.

Comment: if it was my choice I would have retired it, unfortunately it's not so easy... and HP still supports it till 2025 if I'm not mistaken :(

Comment: Well, nobody can build git-lfs for HP-UX without Go, and nobody has ported Go to HP-UX. If your company is going to spend all this money keeping this antique running, maybe they'll spend some money on developers to port Go to HP-UX... (or not)

Comment: OK Thanks, so I believe the answer to my question is simply: NO :)